# Firebase Management API projects.addFirebase permission denied

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

Problem: Firebase Management API method projects.addFirebase returns status code 403

Steps to recreate:

In an Android application I need to create separate Firebase Accounts for Realtime Database. For this purpose I authenticate users with GoogleSignIn. 
Then I retrieve token with proper scope "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform".
In next step I use GCP Resource Manager API to create a new GCP project, which will be a container for Firebase project.

The new project is created successfully on each of the test accounts.

When I try to call Firebase Management API method projects.addFirebase using the same token I got earlier (same scope) I get error "The caller does not have permission". This error occurs on 3 out of 4 accounts I have tried.

I was able to reproduce same error also using google-apis-explorer. [Apis Explorer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/addFirebase)

I will be grateful for any hints on how to resolve this issue. As I mentioned earlier this error does not occur on one of the accounts I tested, while on the remaining three it happens every time.

Thank you.

**Update**

@Doug thank you for taking time to look at my problem. It seems that I have found the cause. After accessing https://console.firebase.google.com and clicking "Add a project" a following popup showed up (I can't paste it directly, because my reputation is too low):

[Popup link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z46kR.png)

After I checked all consents and added first project I am also able to make api calls successfully.

It looks like I my question should be: Is there a way to grant required permissions through Resource Manager Api calls so I can add Firebase to existing Cloud Project?

Also for the reference I paste the method I use to call projects.addFirebase, it uses RxJava2 (Android) and Retrofit2.

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
@POST("projects/{project}:addFirebase")
Single<Operation> addFirebaseToProject(@Header("Authorization") String bearerToken,
                                       @Path("project") String project,
                                       @Body FirebaseDataModel dataModel
);
```

Thank you for your help.

Ps. sorry for my bad English, it's not my mother tongue.

Comment: Without showing the minimal complete code to reproduce the problem, there is nothing we can do to help.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your help. I updated the question.