# 403 The caller does not have permission for Firebase Management API addFirebase

Tags: firebase, google-api, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I want to add Firebase project through Firebase Management Api. So for that. I made project on Google Cloud Platform console. And created service account with permission as a owner.

I tried to read and create project throw google api explorer for [addFirebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/addFirebase?authuser=1) and it works. But when i try to do the same through my code it read [availableProject](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/availableProjects/list) successfully and give output as

> {
>     "projectInfo": [
>       {
>         "project": "projects/firebase-api-238012",
>         "displayName": "Firebase-Api"
>       }
>     ]
>   }

but when i try to add project it give me this error

> {
>     "error": {
>       "code": 403,
>       "message": "The caller does not have permission",
>       "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
>     }
>   }

I don't know why its is not creating project. What other permission it needs. And why it allowed to me read available projects first.

here is how i am trying to add my project.

jwt.js

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
var serviceAccountJwt = require('./Firebase-Api-b0e41b85ad44.json');

exports.connect = async () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // scope is based on what is needed in our api
    const scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'];

    // create our client with the service account JWT
    const { client_email, private_key } = serviceAccountJwt;
    const client = new google.auth.JWT(client_email, null, private_key, scope, null);

    // perform authorization and resolve with the client

    return client.authorize((err) => {
        if (err) { reject(err) }
        else {
            resolve(client)
        };
    });
});
```

}

index.js file

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const request = require('request');
const { connect } = require('./jwt');
const availableProjects = 'https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/availableProjects';


async function getAccessToken() {
let client = await connect();
let accessToken = await client.getAccessToken();
let res = await getProjects(accessToken.token)
}

getAccessToken().catch(err => {
console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
})

const bodys = {
"timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
"locationId": "asia-south1",
"regionCode": "US"
}

async function getProjects(accesstoken) {

let options = {
url: availableProjects,
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken,
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
}

return request(options, async function (err, res) {
if (err) {
  console.error(err + " error");
 } else {
  //here it gives successful output
  console.log("response")
  console.log(res.body);
  let bodyJson = JSON.parse(res.body);
  let projectName = bodyJson.projectInfo[0].project;
  console.log(projectName)
  await addProject(accesstoken, projectName)
  return res.body;
 }
 });
 }

async function addProject(accesstoken, projecctID) {

 fbUrl = getAddFBUrl(projecctID);
 let options = {
 url: fbUrl,
  headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken,
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body:JSON.stringify(bodys)
 }

return request.post(options, function (err, res) {
 if (err) {
  console.error(err + " error");
 } else {
//here in response out put as permission denied 403
  console.log("response")
  console.log(res.body);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
  return res.body;
 }

 });
}


function getAddFBUrl(projectId) {
return 'https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/' + projectId + 
':addFirebase';
}
```

i found one similar question to this. But it didn't helped me to resolve my issue which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54773388/3779368)

## AskFirebase

Comment: Hey man, I'm facing a similar issue when I try to add firebase programmatically. Were you able to fix it somehow?

Comment: Hey bro, I haven't got any solution yet.

Comment: Bro, Have you got any solution?

Comment: @VaradMondkar please read comment of below answer. Hope u will get some help from there. But I have moved to different task. I am not working on it and i have not tried it further. If it helps you and you got success. Please give answer so that it will be helpful to others

Comment: @FaisalAhmed Thanks for reply. Will let you know if I get solution.

Comment: I faced an error like this. The best workaround is to login to Firebase (on the browser) and use the GUI to add the Project from Google Cloud Platform. Did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

From the Firebase REST reference: Method: projects.addFirebase

> To call projects.addFirebase, a member must be an Editor or Owner for
>   the existing GCP Project. <s>**Service accounts cannot call
>   projects.addFirebase.**</s>

Update:

> To call projects.addFirebase, a project member or **service account** must have the following permissions (the IAM roles of Editor and Owner contain these permissions): firebase.projects.update, resourcemanager.projects.get, serviceusage.services.enable, and serviceusage.services.get.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/addFirebase

Comment: Dear @ersin-ertan. I think you didn't read my question properly. Where, I have mentioned in second line that i have **created service account with permission as a owner**. However thanks for your response

Comment: Hi @FaisalAhmed it is not clear to me why you emphasized creating the service account with the owner permission. The way that I am understanding the reference is that service accounts cannot call the API regardless of what permission they have.

Comment: But, I was able to read available project through API using service accounts.Please read my question where i have mentioned it clearly

Comment: @FaisalAhmed no need to be rude by repeatedly telling me to read the question. I was hesitant to follow up because of that. I'm trying to help *you* understand that you can't do this operation with a service account. Where does it mention that because you were able to list projects, that qualifies the service account to add a project? These are two different operations. Please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Hey @ersin-ertan. Sorry if that sound rude to you. I got the point you were trying to say.

Comment: For those, who might have more than 1 Firebase account: **remember to switch to the correct one, which is appropriate for the project you want to run**.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if my answer will be helpful for author of this question, but this if first two things all should check when facing 403 Error with Google Cloud APIs

**0) Check configuration with gcloud**

**1) As mentioned before the first thing is to check the role of service account. You need Editor/Owner usually.**

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin

[image]

[image]

**2) The second one is to check if API enabled for project at all.**

[image]
[image]

**Also when creating a key check it for correct service account.**

Answer (score 2):

For someone who's just get started like me, this thing maybe helpful. When I seted up database, I choose **Start in locked mode** instead of **Start in test mode**. Therefore, I can't read or write :((. For beginner, just set everything in test mode. Hope it helpful.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVxjk.png

Answer (score 1):

Your problem means that your project is not linked with your firebase account which means you have to login with your firebase account. Than you will have the permission

1. type `cd functions` in your firebase project directory
2. type `firebase login`
3. login with the Gmail which is connected with your firebase account

It'll work

Comment: Hey @Abdullah Bhojani!  Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for contributing.  I added formatting to help with readability, but you should still explain why the steps will work (in addition to the steps themselves).  This is recommended practice so that the question asker can also understand why they're doing what you're recommending.  Hope this helps.